# Javascript Regex - contains word AND word from list in any order

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have a requirement to find a specific word AND any words from a list. So far I have this:

```
^.*?(apple)(?:\W+\w+){0,30}?\W+(ipad|itunes).*
```

This matches "apple" and either "ipad" or "itunes".

This fails however if "ipad" or "itunes" is before "apple".

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better use lookahead for that:

```
/^(?=.*?\bapple\b)(?=.*?\b(ipad|itunes)\b).*$/i
```

**Update:** As per this comment from OP: `Can you advise how my word limit would fit in here? e.g. I must find any from the list within 20 words of apple?`

```
/^(?=.*?\bapple\b)(?=.*?\bapple(\W+\w+){0,20}\b(ipad|itunes)\b).*$/i
```

Comment: Can you advise how my word limit would fit in here? e.g. I must find any from the list within 20 words of apple?

Comment: Many thanks for the update, however thats not working for me using http://refiddle.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the simple version work ( http://jsfiddle.net/xhdBQ/1/ ) ?

```
var list = ["ipad", "itunes"];
var word = "apple";
list.push(word)

var regex = new RegExp("(" + list.join("|") + ")", "g");
console.log(regex);
console.log("blabla...apple,,safsd ssdfipadaad itunes".match(regex))
```